# How can you reliably use relative units for background-position when using a background-image with background-size=cover?

Tags: css

I've run into an issue when using `background-position` in a div along with `background-size: cover`. There seem to be some quirks in the browsers calculations, so I'm looking for a reliable way of doing this.

**More detail...**

The use case is mostly visual and everything in the interface should scale nicely. In the past I've has good results by either using rem or em units for everything.

At the start or when the screen size changes I'm measuring the available screen space and then set an appropriate `font-size` on the  container. Something like this...

```
const size = calculateSize();
$("#container").css({fontSize: size + 'px'});
```

Generally, it works very nicely. Everything scales and positions itself properly - or does it?

I recently added a graphic button - a  with a background image.

```
.button {
    background-image: url("img/button.png");
    background-size: cover;
    width: 10em;
    height: 4.5em;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.button:hover {
    background-position-x: -100%;
}
```

I did also try `background-position-x: -10em`, but I prefer the percentage notation as it takes care of itself if I resize the button image.

That's when I started noticing a small, but annoying problem. When I hover over the button, it moves just a little bit. The amount varies depending on how large the available space is. It's usually only a pixel or 2 at the most. It seems equally affected by Chrome, Firefox, and Edge.

It might not seem like much, and maybe I can just accept it as a *feature*, but I'm wondering if anyone else has experienced this and found a way around it.

One likely solution would be to just use separate images for the different button states, but I prefer keeping the number of images to a minimum.

**UPDATE:** So, I just tried creating 2 separate images, and then changed the CSS accordingly...

```
.button {
    background-image: url("img/button0.png");
    background-size: cover;
    width: 10em;
    height: 4.5em;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.button:hover {
    background-image: url("img/button1.png");
    /* background-position-x: -100%; */
}
```

This does make the wobble movement go away, so I'm pretty confident it's some specific issue with how the browser is interpreting `background-position-x`. Being such a small movement, I suspect it's some sort of rounding error.

**Minimal, Reproducible Example:**

In an attempt to ensure I wasn't just seeing things, I put together a jsFiddle that illustrates the problem...

https://jsfiddle.net/xtempore/nfLh86sm/8/

I made a simplified version of the button image. It's just black on the left half and very pale grey on the right. Then I put it into 4 different divs each with a different `font-size`.

When you hover, you should just see the rectangle change from black to grey. And on the 1st and 3rd ones it does. But check out the 2nd and 4th ones! When you hover, there's a sneaky little bit of black appears on the left-hand edge.

The units used are pretty straightforward in this case. The problem seems to appear with odd-numbered pixels. In my case sometimes these `font-size`s will also include decimals (e.g. 15.45px).

Comment: is that really all the css that affects button:hover? inspect and have a look as to why it moves.

Comment: @Joel Yes. That's all of it. It's the browsers rendering that's the problem.

Comment: compensate for it by using negative padding in your `:hover`

Comment: @Joel The problem is that it's not consistent. In some cases it doesn't move and sometimes it does. Trying to fudge it with padding will just make it wrong other times. I suspect it's some sort of rounding error in the browser as it converts between relative units and pixels.

Comment: Well. since you didn't provide me with a [mcve] there is nothing I can do for you.

Comment: @Joel *There is no such thing as **negative padding**.*

Comment: @Paulie_D https://jsfiddle.net/8sbntpgk/

Comment: @Joel That's not *negative* padding, that's *different* padding.

Comment: @Paulie_D 48px on hover from 50px non-hover, how could you quantify that? We're talking about a fixed size, reducing that size on hover, from the original size i.e. (48-50) => -2. Cmon... Don't be literate.

Comment: As I said it's **different** padding.... which is entirely literate and accurate. Padding does not not take a *negative* value so there's no such thing as *negative padding*. If you'd said "use smaller padding" that would have made more sense.

Comment: How browsers resolve sub pixel distances is pretty complicated and differs between browsers. It's been well demonstrated that whatever resolution strategy is used, some problems will occur in one scenario or another. But, in my experience, Firefox's strategy works out better than Chrome's more often than vice-versa, and that appears to be the case here as well, at least with your jsfiddle.

Comment: @Alohci You are right! I'm not sure why my actual code gives some movement in Firefox, but it doesn't show the problem in the fiddle.

Comment: @Paulie_D I think I found a solution. I've changed the title to be more specific, detailed the desired result and made clear the minimal reproducible result. I'm sure I'm not the only one who will have run into this problem, and I think there's valuable information here. Can you please reopen it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem demonstrates an issue with rendering in the common browsers (Chrome, Firefox, Edge), but I managed to find an alternate method that gives the desired result.

Instead of using...

```
background-size: cover;
```

... you can use a percentage, for example ...

```
background-size: 200%;
```

If your base image is 2 sprites wide, i.e. contains two images for different states side-by-side, then the specified `background-size` should be 200%. Similarly, if you have 3 times the size, 300%, and so on.

This gives the desired scaling, even as the div changes size.

You can see that the problem is resolved in the example fiddle by just changing that value from `cover` to `200%`.

With problem: https://jsfiddle.net/xtempore/nfLh86sm/8/

No problem: https://jsfiddle.net/xtempore/2vcg4h1L/

I hope this helps someone else who is getting these weird side-effects.